# Error al hacer un redirect() hacia una vista: "Reverse not found. is not a valid view function or pattern name."

Tags: python, django

soy novato en Django (2.2) y Python (3.7.2) y estoy teniendo problemas al iniciar un proyecto. Me encuentro en una vista que, a resultas de un submit en una template, intenta redireccionar a otra vista:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.urls import reverse, path

def index_app(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        client_id=request.POST.get('client_id')
        return redirect('app:login_app',{'client_id':client_id})
    return render(request,'app/index_app.html')

def login_app(request,client_id):
    return render(request,'app/login_app.html',{'client_id':client_id})
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'app'
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index_app,name='index_app'),
    path('<int:client_id>/',views.login_app, name='login_app'),
]
```

Cuando debe hacer el `return redirect(...)` me encuentro con el siguiente error:

```
Reverse for 'login_app' with arguments '({'client_id': '12'},)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['app/(?P<client_id>[0-9]+)/$']
```

¿Qué está ocurriendo?

Comment: ¿Qué patrones de URL tienes? Además, ¿qué versión de Django estás usando?

Comment: revisa tu view si existe `login_app` probablemente se llame `login`

Comment: por cierto reverse se encuentra en `from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse` desde la version 1.10 de Django

Comment: @JackNavaRow la view login_app se encuentra justo ahí.

Comment: @fedorqui acabo de editar la consulta poniendo las urls y las versiones

Comment: te sugiero usar el render "return render(request, "mi_template.html", context=context)"...

Comment: Jordi, la pregunta que hiciste ayer es muy similar. Es la misma, o estas preguntando otra cosa? Ademas lo que pusiste como respuesta ayer no deberia ser una respuesta. Si esa pregunta no sirve mas, por favor eliminala. Si la pregunta es la misma, sigamos con una sola.

Comment: @gbianchi la pregunta es otra dado que es diferente error. No viendo salida a la via que seguia he decidido hacerlo de otra manera, como explicaba en la pregunta de ayer. Ahora me he encontrado con un nuevo problema. He intentado eliminar la pregunta de ayer pero parece que no es posible.

Comment: @DiegoAvila he hecho lo que me dices y sí que me funciona, me va directamente a la template y me pasa el client_id, pero lo interesante es que pase por la función "login_app" pues ahí tendré que hacer unas comprobaciones antes de llamar a la template

Comment: He encontrado el problema. La llamada debería ser tal que ```return redirect('app:login_app',client_id)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A la función `redirect` le tienes que pasar una URL o nombre de la ruta definida en el archivo `urls.py`.

En tu caso la función `index_app` quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


def index_app(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        client_id = request.POST.get('client_id')
        return redirect('login_app', {'client_id': client_id})

    return render(request, 'app/index_app.html')
```

Te dejo link a la documentación de Django sobre la función `redirect`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect

Comment: Gracias Saúl. he tenido que hacer la llamada ```return redirect('app:login_app', client_id)``` Con esto me ha funcionado